# How do i fix carbon throwing undefined mixin error

Tags: css, sass, svelte, rollup, carbon-design-system

I want to use the dark theme g90 in Carbon design system.
I can get the default white theme by importing these:

```
<style lang="scss" global>
  @use "@carbon/themes";
  @include themes.set(themes.$g90);

  @import 'carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/_css--reset.scss';
  @import 'carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/_css--font-face.scss';
  @import 'carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/_css--helpers.scss';
  @import 'carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/_css--body.scss';

  @import 'carbon-components/scss/globals/grid/_grid.scss';

  @import 'carbon-components/scss/components/button/button';

</style>
```

However, i get a error when compiling.

```
[!] (plugin svelte) Error: Undefined mixin.
  ╷
3 │     @include themes.set(themes.$g90);
  │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/App.svelte 3:2  root stylesheet
```

The only thing i have changed from the `svelte/template` is

```
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      preprocess: [
        autoPreprocess({
          postcss: true,
          scss: { includePaths: ["src", "node_modules"] },
        }),
```

I have tried for hours and am missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mathias!

I am using carbon myself (v11) and it looks like you are using a combination of v10 tactics and v11 tactics.

@carbon/theme won't get you anything.

It should either be, `@use 'carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/themes'` (v10) or `@use '@carbon/styles/scss/theme';`(v11)

In v11 carbon, I am importing and using like this

*`app.scss`*

```
@use '@carbon/react/scss/themes';
@use '@carbon/react/scss/theme' with (
  $theme: themes.$g100,
);


@use '@carbon/react';
```

The styles are prepackaged in `@carbon/react` and must be added AFTER the theme.

Let me know if any of that helped?

Comment: It did help, but i had to change a few things to get it to work in svelte. Do you know how to change colors?

Comment: Just change the $g100. You could use $g90, $g10, or $white

Comment: Bro, i love you !! it works

Comment: Dude, you saved my day. I read and reread the documentation and was unable to do this. In 5 lines you helped me more than IBM, lol
Thank you!

Comment: @asihej working at IBM has it's perks lol

Comment: Thanks for this! The examples in their official documentation were giving me compile errors, this just works.